# PDF Manipulation on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, quartz-graphics

I have been reading Apple's docs and they recommend using UIWebView.  This is all well and good until you want to go to a page number and also search PDF's.

Is there any 3rd Party libraries, (free or paid) that do this at all?

As a minimum I need to be able to Search and goto a page number in a PDF.

I have looked and PDFKit is not available and the Quartz methods seem limited.  This is obviously possible due to the amount of PDF readers available on the app store.

Comment: Here's one PDF library for iOS: http://mobfarm.eu/fastpdfkit https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

Comment: is app store approved this, if i use this with my application?
https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do all that just using the Quartz calls. Quartz is obviously C-based, so it takes a moment to adjust to the lack of square brackets, but functions are named clearly and it's not too hard to figure out. For example, you can use CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(), CGPDFDocumentGetPage(), and CGContextDrawPDFPage() to display a given page from a document. There's a nice explanation of searching a PDF here: [Random Ideas](http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42)

None of this is to say that a 3rd party framework is a bad idea -- if someone has already done the work to make this all easy, then great. But if you don't find something that suits you, don't be afraid to dig into Quartz -- it's not bad.

Comment: The link has been moved to http://web.archive.org/web/20131122162015/http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184